# Setting up S3+Cloudfront en masse

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an AWS account with an "example.com" hosted zone and a *.example.com arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:XXXXXX:certificate/uuid ready to go.

I need to set up several sites, `{1..10}.example.com`. Each site I would ideally have an S3 bucket in my local region ap-southeast-1 with the same name and a CloudFront distribution set in front of each one.

I tried Terraform but I stalled since https://github.com/ringods/terraform-website-s3-cloudfront-route53/tree/master/site-redirect seemed far too complex.

I tried https://github.com/widdix/aws-cf-templates/blob/master/static-website/static-website.yaml, but that failed with "No export named -HostedZoneId found."

I also tried https://github.com/taimos/cloudformation/blob/master/static-website/static-website.yaml which got pretty close. The only major issue is that it seems to expect I create {1..10}.example.com zones in advance in Route53. I am not sure why it can't just populate the existing *example.com* zone with the CloudFront addresses. Furthermore, I didn't like how it uses www.{1..10}.example.com by default. I do not want *www* prefix/subdomain.

I feel like me use case is fairly simple and popular, but I am struggling to find a solution. Any pointers? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *I am not sure why it can't just populate the existing example.com zone with the CloudFront addresses.* 
Well, you can... just not with this template, as written.  *Furthemore I didn't like how it uses www.{1..10}.example.com by default. I do not want www prefix/subdomain.*  Okay, so remove that.  It is unclear what you are asking us to do, here.  Questions looking for programming help are welcome, but you haven't written this as a programming question -- it's written as a "looking for a canned solution" question.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how the CloudFront YAML even needs to change.